# How do I assign each value between a colon into a new variable? So 08:10:20 Would be hours,minutes and Seconds

Tags: vb.net, string

How do I assign each value between a colon into a new variable?  So 08:10:20 Would be hours,minutes and Seconds In VB.NET?

So

- Hours would be equal to 8
- Minutes would be equal to 10
- Seconds would be equal to 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to parse a delimited string like that would be do do something like this:

```
Dim parts() As String = value.Split(":"c)
Dim hours As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
Dim minutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
Dim seconds As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(2))
```

However, if what you really want is a `Date` object, then you could just do this:

```
Dim d As Date = Date.ParseExact(value, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The "HH" means 24-hour time.  If you want 12-hour time, use lower-case ("hh").